# Flutter hide onscreenkeyboard on android Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, flutter, external

iam developing a Flutter app to acquire numbers via an extrernal Bluetooth Scanner which acts like a normal Keyboard.

If i tap on the TextInputField the native android Keyboard pops up to enter text, which is fine, but i need to supress the keyboard since iam going to scan Barcodes and i need the full Screen to see my scanned Barcodes.

@Barcodes: these are only 12-digit long numbers.

so far,
axp

Answer (score 0):

My scanner is an Android phone, here is what I've done:

- Implemented Kotlin code to hide keyboard
- Created a method channel
- Invoke method in Flutter where I needed to hide soft keyboard

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44681#issuecomment-962110920

Answer (score -1):

//I created this solution based it works for iOS and Android both.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class QRCodeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  QRCodeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QRCodeScreenState createState() => _QRCodeScreenState();
}

class _QRCodeScreenState extends State<QRCodeScreen> {
  FocusNode node = NoKeyboardEditableTextFocusNode();
  TextEditingController scanController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() { 
    node.requestFocus();
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      () {
          SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.invisible');
      }
    );
    super.initState();
    
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
         child: IgnorePointer(
           child: Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 TextField(
                   controller: scanController,
                   focusNode: node,
                   autofocus: true,
                   decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "WAITING FOR QR CODE..."),
                   ),
  SizedBox(height:50),
               ],
             ),
               
           ),
         ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    node.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


class NoKeyboardEditableTextFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool consumeKeyboardToken() {
    return false;
  }
}
```